# Может ли точка стоять в середине предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Написав в одном из вопросов *А вот предложение "Здравствуйте." мы отнесём к побудительным*, я, поколебавшись, поставила точку после *Здравствуйте* (конец предложения всё-таки). Модератор заменил после точки строчную "м" на заглавную. Получилось несколько неуклюже. Если после *Здравствуйте* не ставить точку, то смысл не изменится, и так все понятно. Поэтому, мне кажется, правильнее было бы убрать точку.
 Как же всё-таки правильно оформить такое предложение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элен,в научной литературе не принято такие вещи оформлять с помощью кавычек.Вот передо мной учебник Валгиной "Современный русский язык". Цитирую:

"Так, в предложении В продолжение двух дней мои дела ужасно продвинулись(Л.) выражается наличие связи между представлением о делах как предметах речи и тем, что о них говорится,- продвинулись; в предложении К счастью, по причине неудачной охоты, наши кони не были измучены (Л.) выражается отсутствие связи между предметом речи и его признаком."
Как видите, передаётся содержание предложения, при этом само предложение пишется с большой буквы, но бех кавычек и знаков конца. Знаки эмоциональные - восклицательный и вопросительный - ставятся, точка - нет. Это не прямая речь.

Кстати, если даже принять за чужую речь, то, если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или когда приводится общеизвестная пословица либо поговорка, кавычки не ставятся, например: Дома и хворать легче и жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: дома стены помогают (Чехов); Про Ивашку Бровкина говорили: крепкий(А.Н. Толстой)

К тому же Здравствуйте - не предложение в строгом смысле, а этикетная формула, высказывание.

Comment: Кавычки в подобных изданиях опускаются не по причине того, что это правильно, а просто из соображений наглядности. Иначе весь текст будет пестреть кавычками. Аналогично поступают в и текстах с постоянным упоминанием имен собственных, требующих кавычек: названий предприятий, кулинарных рецептов и проч. В таких случаях вместо кавычек обычно используется другое зрительное выделение, курсив, например. Все вполне законно и разумно, но ссылаться на этот прием как на авторитетный, тем более - как на правило, имхо, не стоит.

Comment: Не думаю. Думаю, что именно потому, что правильно.Кавычками выделяется что-то в условном, необычном значении, а это именно предложение(в широком смысле, высказывание), а не что-то другое. На "Ответах" со мной спорили, говорили, что нужно писать так: буква "А",слово "...", наречие"громко".Это неверно.Это именно буква, в кавычки брать не нужно. Так и предложение, его содержание в кавычки брать не нужно.

Comment: А вот "правильно" в подобных вопросах у нас только то, что подтверждается ссылками на правило. Орфографическое, разумеется, не на Устав внутренних редакторских войск. Рассуждения и воспоминания принимаются максимум как пояснения к правилу.

Comment: Ну не знаю я таких правил.Ссылку не могу дать, только  на то, что вижу в практике, в "правильных" книгах профессоров лингвистики, наших учителей. Для меня это авторитетно,служит примером.

Answer (score 2):

Точки не надо. Фрагмент, заключенный в кавычки представляет собой самостоятельную фразу, но точка перед кавычками обычно опускается. Правда, на этот счет рекомендации несколько расплывчаты, но из того, что можно понять, вполне следует необходимость опустить точку (или вынести её за кавычки, если это конец всего предложения).

Например, здесь:
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=oszp

§ 199. Перед закрывающими кавычками не ставятся точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие и тире. Все эти знаки ставятся только после кавычек...

Примеры, правда, не совсем удачны, там нет законченных фраз  в кавычках, но всё-таки смысл утверждения вполне однозначен.

А вообще после "Здравствуйте" обычен восклицательный знак. С ним такихъ заморочек не возникает.

Answer (score 1):

А вот предложение: "Здравствуйте" - мы отнесём к побудительным.

Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, надпись, выражение и т.п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например:

Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные, также отдаются напрокат и починяются старые".

Так как после кавычек предложение продолжается, то нужно поставить тире: по правилу о прямой речи внутри слов автора.

Comment: Было очень тихо, пахло сырым полем. (Бун.) 
 Все тихо, просто было в ней. (П.)
  В первом предложении тихо — предикативное наречие, во втором — краткое прилагательное;

Comment: Предикативные наречия, омонимичные кратким прилагательным среднего рода, имеют степени сравнения: В лесу было тихо. (Сим.) В лесах становилось все сумрачнее, все тише. (Пауст.)

Comment: >по правилу о прямой речи внутри слов автора.  
  
Здесь нет прямой речи. И нет слов автора, к ней прямо относящихся. так что трактовка как минимум неочевидна.

Comment: на сайте Института русского языка http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=1275

 Девочка пела песенки под возгласы «Браво!». (элемент предложения)
Ему требовалось ответить только на один вопрос: «..?» (прямая речь)

Он закончил речь фразой: «..?» (прямая речь)
Держали плакаты с надписью: «..!» (прямая речь)

А вот предложение "Здравствуйте" мы отнесём к побудительным.

Или 

А вот предложение: "Здравствуйте" - мы отнесём к побудительным.

Comment: Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например:  Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец...» и отошел в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.
Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, надпись, выражение, то ставится двоеточие: 

Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные, также отдаются напрокат и починяются старые» (Пушкин).

Comment: Мимо станции проносились скорые поезда с табличками на вагонах: «Москва —Владивосток»; 

Разберите предложение: «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».

Comment: Вопрос: "Как судить: по закону или по справедливости?" – по-прежнему актуален.

Comment: Высказывание Паскаля: «Кто умеет внушить, что он не очень хитер, тот уже далеко не прост» - звучит афористично; 
Слова Пикассо: «Искусство - это эманация боли и печали» - имеют глубокий смысл.